# Several file upload controls only upload one file

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I browsed through numerous previous topics and however I did find more than a few great answers, I can't find solution to my particular problem. Not that it's uniqe in any way, I am just new to PHP and don't know what to do.

I made and HTML form for a website I'm doing, sort of job application form. Client demanded three pictures upload. I scrabmled a form and a PHP code for it, but managed to upload only 1 file, using the code of my choosing.

How do I get more than one file uploaded?

HTML form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">*Pictures</label>
      <input type="file" name ="filename" id="InputFile"/>
      <input type="file" name ="filename" id="InputFile"/>
      <input type="file" name ="filename" id="InputFile"/>

</div>
```

and PHP:

```
 <?php


    $fileatt      = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    $fileatt_type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
    $fileatt_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];


   $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['job_email'];

    if (is_uploaded_file($fileatt)) {
     $file = fopen($fileatt,'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
     fclose($file);

     $semi_rand = md5(time());
     $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

     $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
     " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


     $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $message . "\n\n";


     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));


     $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
     " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .

     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
    }

    $ok = @mail("xxxx@gmail.com", $subject , $message, $headers); 
    if ($ok) {
    echo "<p>Well done</p>";
    } else {
    echo "<p>Please try again</p>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Heh heh: "scrabmled" `:)`.

Comment: The problem is your file `input` controls have clashing `name` and `id` attributes. If you want to upload multiple files, you will need to be able to refer to the form data uniquely (via the name). And, in an HTML document, clashing id attributes result in invalid HTML. So, fix these first. I'd say "filename" isn't such a good name - try "image1", "image2", "image3"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in your form input name should be like that if you want to upload multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name ="filename[]" id="InputFile" />
<input type="file" name ="filename[]" id="InputFile" />
<input type="file" name ="filename[]" id="InputFile" />
```

Or one input as @Undefined_variable said which let you choose multiple images per one time:

```
<input type="file" name ="filename[]" id="InputFile" multiple />
```

When I recommend rearray your $_FILES[] :

```
function rearray(&$file_post) {

     $file_ary = array();
     $file_count = count($file_post['name']);
     $file_keys = array_keys($file_post);

     for ($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++) {
         foreach ($file_keys as $key) {
             $file_ary[$i][$key] = $file_post[$key][$i];
         }
     }

     return $file_ary;
 }
$files = rearray($_FILES['filename']);
 
foreach($files as $file){
$tmpname = $file["tmp_name"];/// use $file like $_FILES[..]["temp_name"] etc.
}
```

You should read a bit more about uploading multiple files with php, and try to find out solution.
Read more: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 0):

if you are using HTML5 then this can help

```
<input type="file" name ="filename" id="InputFile" multiple />
```

it will work in ie 10, mozilla, chrome (Ie 9 and below does not support multiple file upload)